# Is the HTML <link rel="canonical"> about URL or content or both?

Tags: html, seo, canonical-link

Does the HTML `<link rel="canonical">` refer to URL or content or both?

I have a part of a website done in pure HTML + CSS + JavaScript and no server side. When a user enters the site with the root URL, the `/index.htm` is loaded. The root `index.htm` redirects to `/site1/index.htm`.

I would like to indicate that the canonical URL for `/site1/index.htm` should be `/index.htm`, and the canonical URL for that, in turn, should be `/`, so if needed at a later time, the redirect can go elsewhere. In this sense, specifying a canonical URL is intended to indicate that users should always enter the site through the specified path if possible when arriving at `/site1/index.htm`.

I'm wondering if specifying `<link rel="canonical" href="/index.htm">` in `/site1/index.htm`, and `<link rel="canonical" href="/">` in `/index.htm` would accomplish this. (I'm aware that absolute URLs are recommended, but this may not always be possible.)

The web server could be IIS, Apache, or other. I can't touch the server config or headers or htaccess.

Can this be done in HTML or possibly JavaScript? (I'm aware that JavaScript won't affect SEO, but it may have something to do with the redirect. Currently, the redirect is done using both meta refresh and JavaScript `location = ''`, with a fallback link for the user to click. As mentioned, can't touch headers, or server config.)

Further, if `<link rel="canonical">` is used in said fashion, would search engines index the content of the target in place of the specifying page? For example, would search engines assume the content of `/site1/index.htm` is the same as `/index.htm`, so that the URL `/site1/index.htm` would get associated with the actual contents of `/index.htm`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network [ProWebmaster](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Without the last paragraph (what search engine do/don’t do), the question should be on-topic here. The whole thing should be on-topic on [webmasters.se], though.

Comment: If it's more acceptable, I can remove the last paragraph as @unor suggests, or if anyone cares to edit, that's fine by me...

Comment: Everyone, should I delete this question (or make a duplicate in webmasters, since nobody is answering), or remove the last paragraph, or is there a way to move this to webmasters? I thought the question would be largely acceptable here. The part about what the search engines would do, was actually a question about any spec/de-facto defining what they should do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new here so I don't know if this is out of topic or not but I'll try to answer the question.

The `<link rel="canonical">` is kind of straight forward. It works like this.

When a search engine spider crawls your page it tells him what URL should be indexed for that particular page. It's very usefull in cases of possible different URL access to a particular content. (one example within others non-www and www URLs)

Exemple : You have multiple products pages for a specific category on your website because you use pagination. In this case you will have several URLs for your paginated content page 1, page 2, page 3, etc... Adding a `<link rel="canonical">` tag pointing to the first page to all these pages will tell the search engine that it should index the first page only instead of indexing all paginated pages.

Basically your telling the spider don't index this URL index that other URL instead.

In your particular case `/index.htm` is most probably a 301 redirection to `/site1/index.htm`. The risk is that Google won't index your page because you are telling it not to index the content on `/site1/index.htm` and index `index.htm` instead but this page has no content because it provides a redirection.

I'm aware that you stated that you have no access to the .htaccess file but the only way I can thing of without touching your folders structure on your FTP is to use .htaccess to rewrite `/site1/index.htm` to `/index.htm` and then add the canonical tag just to be safe because having a canonical tag is a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Bennetonable. One of the points I'm still not clear about is, if you specify a canonical pointing to page1 in all the other pages, by your explanation, wouldn't the spiders be expected to index the content of page1 in place of the content of the other pages? So, in essence, a user would not be able to get search hits for content in the other pages? This is one of the points I was trying convey in my op...

Comment: This is exactly the case, If all your website pages have a canonical URL pointing to you homepage then only the homepage will make it to the search engine index and already indexed pages will slowly be dropped. 

However for this to work you will have to have content on the specified canonical URL, not a 301 redirection to another URL.